# Add link to the product title on WooCommerce product_page shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

On the homepage of our website, we have added a shortcode to show the product page of the featured product.

I have added a SKU 'featured' to the featured product, so I could use the following shortcode to show the featured product `[product_page sku="featured"]`.

Now I would like to modify the code of the shortcode so the name of the product links to the full featured product page.

Below is the WooCommerce that sets up the product_page.

```
/**
 * Show a single product page.
 *
 * @param array $atts Attributes.
 * @return string
 */
public static function product_page( $atts ) {
    if ( empty( $atts ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( ! isset( $atts['id'] ) && ! isset( $atts['sku'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'      => 1,
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'no_found_rows'       => 1,
    );

    if ( isset( $atts['sku'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'     => '_sku',
            'value'   => sanitize_text_field( $atts['sku'] ),
            'compare' => '=',
        );

        $args['post_type'] = array( 'product', 'product_variation' );
    }

    if ( isset( $atts['id'] ) ) {
        $args['p'] = absint( $atts['id'] );
    }

    // Don't render titles if desired.
    if ( isset( $atts['show_title'] ) && ! $atts['show_title'] ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
    }

    // Change form action to avoid redirect.
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', '__return_empty_string' );

    $single_product = new WP_Query( $args );

    $preselected_id = '0';

    // Check if sku is a variation.
    if ( isset( $atts['sku'] ) && $single_product->have_posts() && 'product_variation' === $single_product->post->post_type ) {

        $variation  = new WC_Product_Variation( $single_product->post->ID );
        $attributes = $variation->get_attributes();

        // Set preselected id to be used by JS to provide context.
        $preselected_id = $single_product->post->ID;

        // Get the parent product object.
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'      => 1,
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'no_found_rows'       => 1,
            'p'                   => $single_product->post->post_parent,
        );

        $single_product = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
                var $variations_form = $( '[data-product-page-preselected-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $preselected_id ); ?>"]' ).find( 'form.variations_form' );

                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attr => $value ) { ?>
                    $variations_form.find( 'select[name="<?php echo esc_attr( $attr ); ?>"]' ).val( '<?php echo esc_js( $value ); ?>' );
                <?php } ?>
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }

    // For "is_single" to always make load comments_template() for reviews.
    $single_product->is_single = true;

    ob_start();

    global $wp_query;

    // Backup query object so following loops think this is a product page.
    $previous_wp_query = $wp_query;
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    $wp_query          = $single_product;
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-single-product' );

    while ( $single_product->have_posts() ) {
        $single_product->the_post()
        ?>
        <div class="single-product" data-product-page-preselected-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $preselected_id ); ?>">
            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    // Restore $previous_wp_query and reset post data.
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    $wp_query = $previous_wp_query;
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Re-enable titles if they were removed.
    if ( isset( $atts['show_title'] ) && ! $atts['show_title'] ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
    }

    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', '__return_empty_string' );

    return '<div class="woocommerce">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

You can see they address the product_title with `$atts['show_title']`. So I guess we should wrap this with a href link of the product link, but  I'm afraid my knowledge in that area lacks a bit.

Can somebody assist me with this, please? Much appreciated!

Comment: _“You can see they address the product_title with $atts['show_title'].”_ - that is not the actual product title, that is just an option to determine whether to _show_ the title, or not. Depending on this option, the `woocommerce_template_single_title` function gets removed from / added to the action list.

Comment: You need to build your own shortcode based on the wooCommerce one…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Ok! Is this something you can assist me with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code snippet in your functions.php and have a look.
It will remove the existing title and add new with the anchor tag.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title',5);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_my_single_title',5);

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_my_single_title' ) ) {
   function woocommerce_my_single_title() {
?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><span>dfgdfg<?php the_title(); ?></span></a>
<?php
    }
}
```

**Note**: If it does not remove then you can give some css to hide the existing title based on parent class.

Comment: You are an absolute hero, @momin-iqbal, that works like a treat!